# Browserify - code works in node, but fails in browser after bundling

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, browserify, zipkin

I have got problem running my js application in browser. I have created client-server application, and I am using [Zipkin](http://zipkin.io/) to trace communications between them.

This is the client that uses Node.js `require()`:

```
const {Tracer, BatchRecorder, ExplicitContext} = require('zipkin');
const {HttpLogger} = require('zipkin-transport-http');
const {restInterceptor} = require('zipkin-instrumentation-cujojs-rest');

const rest = require('rest');

const ctxImpl = new ExplicitContext();
const recorder = new BatchRecorder({
    logger: new HttpLogger({
        endpoint: 'http://localhost:9411/api/v1/spans'
    })
});

const tracer = new Tracer({ctxImpl, recorder});
const nameOfClient = 'cujojs-client';
const client = rest.wrap(restInterceptor, {tracer, serviceName: nameOfClient});

client({
    method: 'GET',
    path: 'http://localhost:9999/request'
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log('response: ', response);
});
```

I am using Browserify to bundle dependencies for use in the browser.

I run `browserify CujojsClient.js -o bundle.js` to create bundle for the browser.

If I run browserify with `--node --ignore-missing` options everything works well in Node.js, but when I run the bundle in the browser (Firefox 45.3.0 on windows) I only got:

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
```

This is the problematic part:

```
class HttpLogger {
  constructor({endpoint, httpInterval = 1000}) {
    this.endpoint = endpoint;
    this.queue = [];

    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.processQueue();
    }, httpInterval);
    if (timer.unref) { // unref might not be available in browsers
      timer.unref(); // Allows Node to terminate instead of blocking on timer
    }
  }

  logSpan(span) {
    this.queue.push(span.toJSON());
  }

  processQueue() {
    if (this.queue.length > 0) {
      const postBody = JSON.stringify(this.queue);
      fetch(this.endpoint, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: postBody,
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }).then((response) => {
        if (response.status !== 202) {
          console.error('Unexpected response while sending Zipkin data, status:' +
            `${response.status}, body: ${postBody}`);
        }
        this.queue.length = 0;
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error sending Zipkin data', error);
        this.queue.length = 0;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

My `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using the --node option for a bundle that is run in the browser?

Comment: I am not using the `--node` option for the browser. I run bundled js script in node to test if it works with that option. For browser i use `browserify CujojsClient.js -o bundle.js` with no options.

Comment: I found out that FF 45.3.0 ESR is responsible for the Syntax Errors. On newest browsers the code works.

Comment: Ah ok. As if this stuff wasn't already confusing enough without bugs in FF 

Comment: Don't forget to add your solution as an answer so people in future might benefit from your question :)

Comment: @Dandy I have decided not to integrate tracing into browser, because there is a need to support older browsers (including IE 9 :D) in our project.